# How can I use AWS ami in Azure to launch a VM in azure?

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage, amazon-ami

I have a custom centos 7.4 ami that I use to launch VM in AWS and I want to use the same custom ami in Azure, can I export that ami to azure to launch VM?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot migrate an AWS AMI to Azure VMs. However, you can use tools such as packer.io to minimize the pain of supporting both.

Packer allows you to have a single code base that supports build Images on both Azure and AWS.

Comment: what's the best possible way that I could use packer in my case? I want to use my AMI in AWS?

Comment: Packer has the concept of builders, which allow the images to be built on the platform you desire. The packer template allows for multiple builders to be used. Therefore you can configure a single template to support multiple builders.

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html